# how to customise the tooltip in the line chart in vuejs /chart js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, chart.js, vuejs3

I am trying to draw a line graph using chart js and vue bit new to both vue and chart-js, I in the below chart,I need the tooltip to be changed to "10 Answers July 19,2023" , I tried with beforeLabel and afterLabel options but no luck

[image]

```
<template>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 analytic-container">
    <div class="row title justify-between">
      <div class="answer-count">
        <div class="">Answers</div>
        <h2 v-if="totalAnsCount != 0" class="q-ma-none">{{ totalAnsCount }}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="filter">
        Last
        <q-btn-group flat>
          <q-btn
            :class="btnFlag === 7 ? 'select-interval' : 'unselect-interval'"
            flat
            label="7"
            @click="getChartData(7)"
          />
          <q-btn
            :class="btnFlag === 30 ? 'select-interval' : 'unselect-interval'"
            flat
            label="30"
            @click="getChartData(30)"
          />
          <q-btn
            :class="btnFlag === 90 ? 'select-interval' : 'unselect-interval'"
            flat
            label="90"
            @click="getChartData(90)"
          />
          <q-btn
            :class="btnFlag === 0 ? 'select-interval' : 'unselect-interval'"
            flat
            label="All"
            @click="getChartData(0)"
          />
        </q-btn-group>
        days
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-between">
      <LineChart
        v-if="loaded"
        :data="data"
        :options="options"
        :style="{ height: '150px', width: '100%' }"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  TimeScale,
} from "chart.js";

import { Line as LineChart } from "vue-chartjs";
import "chartjs-adapter-moment";
import { api } from "boot/axios";
import { useUserStore } from "src/stores/user";

// const infoStore = useUserStore();

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  TimeScale
);

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    LineChart,
  },
  props: {
    workspaceUid: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      btnFlag: 0,
      totalAnsCount: 0,
      loaded: false,
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        hover: {
          intersect: false,
        },
        pointRadius: 1,
        plugins: {
          tooltip: {
            displayColors: false,
            callbacks: {
              label: function (context) {
                const label = context.dataset.label || "";
                const value = context.parsed.y;
                return `${label} ${value} Answers`;
              },
            },
          },
        },
        scales: {
          x: {
            type: "time", // Use time scale for X-axis
            time: {
              parser: "YYYY-MM-DD", // Specify the input date format
              unit: "day", // Display ticks as day
              displayFormats: {
                day: "MM/DD", // Format for the X-axis labels (day/month)
              },
              tooltipFormat: "MMMM D, YYYY", // Format for the tooltip
            },
            grid: {
              display: false,
            },
            border: {
              display: true,
              width: 1.5,
              color: "black",
            },
            ticks: {
              font: {
                size: 12, // Change the font size
                weight: "bold", // Set the font weight (e.g., "normal", "bold")
              },
            },
          },
          y: {
            grid: {
              display: false,
            },
            border: {
              display: true,
              width: 1.5,
              color: "black",
            },
            title: {
              display: true,
              color: "black",
              text: "# of Answers",
              font: {
                size: 14,
                weight: "bold",
              },
            },
            ticks: {
              font: {
                size: 12, // Change the font size
                weight: "bold", // Set the font weight (e.g., "normal", "bold")
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [],
            borderColor: "#0d1f91",
            fill: false,
            borderWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.getChartData(7);
  },

  methods: {
    getChartData(interval) {
      this.totalAnsCount = 0;
      this.btnFlag = interval;
      this.loaded = false;
      api
        .get(
          process.env.BASE_URL +
            "/api/strategyAI/analytics/answers/?workspace_uid=" +
            this.workspaceUid +
            "&interval=" +
            interval
        )

        .then((response) => {
          console.log(
            response.data.data.map((item) => item.date),
            response.data.data.map((item) => item.answer_count)
          );
          this.data.labels = response.data.data.map((item) => item.date);
          this.data.datasets[0].data = response.data.data.map(
            (item) => item.answer_count
          );
          this.data.datasets[0].data.forEach((item) => {
            this.totalAnsCount += item;
          });
          this.loaded = true;
        })

        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 0px;
}
.primary {
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.answer-count h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #0d1f91;
  text-align: right;
}
.analytic-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px 15px 15px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* width: 750px; */
  flex-direction: column;
}
.answer-count {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2px 15px;
}
.select-interval {
  background: #acb9c7;
  color: #0d47a1;
  padding: 5px 12px;
}
.unselect-interval {
  background: #fff !important;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 5px 12px;
}
</style>
```

I am trying to draw a line graph using chart js and vue bit new to both vue and chart-js, I in the below chart,I need the tooltip to be changed to "10 Answers July 19,2023" , I tried with beforeLabel and afterLabel options but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `callbacks` property of the tooltip configuration to define a custom function that generates the tooltip label

```
...
tooltip {
  displayColors: false,
  callbacks: {
    title: function () {
      return '';
    },
    label: function (context) {
      const date = context.label;
      const value = context.parsed.y;
      return `${value} Answers ${date}`;
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, much appreciate your effort and time , in the current chatgpt era!!